# c# mysql ошибка при вытаскивании таблиц баз данных

Tags: c#, mysql

winforms приложение, есть локальный сервер, на сервере несколько баз данных, хочу вытаскивать конкретную базу данных и всю таблицу в ней через  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES . но вытаскивает все таблицы включая служебные. как вытащить конкретную базу данных и таблицы этой базы данных? помогите пожалуйста, уже несколько дней мучаюсь этим вопросом. ниже выложил код.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Biling_DSLAM
{
public partial class Openpage : Form
{
    public Openpage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection();
    
    int id;
    string query;



    private void Openpage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {


        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Data Source = 192.168.1.102; UserId = admin; Password = 12345; database = dslam");
        con.Open();
        var command = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();
        command.Connection = con;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES";

        var adapter = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(command);
        var dataset = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dataset);
        DataTable dt = dataset.Tables[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
        con.Close();
    }
    }
   
   
    private DataTable AutoNumberedTable(DataTable SourceTable)

    {
        DataTable ResultTable = new DataTable();
        DataColumn AutoNumberColumn = new DataColumn
        {
            ColumnName = "id",
            DataType = typeof(int),
            AutoIncrement = true,
            AutoIncrementSeed = 1,
            AutoIncrementStep = 1
        };
        ResultTable.Columns.Add(AutoNumberColumn);
        ResultTable.Merge(SourceTable);
        return ResultTable;
    }

    private void Addbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            if (comboBox1.Items.ToString() == "sats 6/0")
            {
                query = "insert into sta60(id, name, surname, phone, login, dslam, port, date) Values (null, '" + Nametextbox.Text + "', '" + Surnametextbox.Text + "', '" + phonetextbox.Text + "', '" + logintextbox.Text + "', '" + dslamcomboBox.Text + "', '" + porttextbox.Text + "', '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "')";
               
            }
           
            if (comboBox1.Items.ToString() == "sats 7/0")
            { 
                query = "insert into sta70(id, name, surname, phone, login, dslam, port, date) Values (null, '" + Nametextbox.Text + "', '" + Surnametextbox.Text + "', '" + phonetextbox.Text + "', '" + logintextbox.Text + "', '" + dslamcomboBox.Text + "', '" + porttextbox.Text + "', '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "')";

            }
           
               MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
            
            con.Open();
                if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Added!");
                }
                con.Close();

             
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error!");
            con.Close();
        }
       
    }

    
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Data Source = 192.168.1.102; database ='" + comboBox1.Text + "'; UserId = admin; password = 12345");
        con.Open();
        DataTable schema = con.GetSchema("Tables");
        foreach(DataRow row in schema.Rows)
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Add(row[2].ToString());
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    
}

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [The INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLES Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-tables-table.html). Написать соотв. `WHERE`.

Comment: `"SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SHEMA = 'dslam' AND TABLE_NAME = 'mytable'"`  типа вот так ? я совсем не правильно вставляю походу

Comment: Ну если не приглядываться к опечаткам в именах полей - то правильно, буде нужна только одна таблица. Если все - то условие по TABLE_NAME лишнее.

Comment: вот такую ошибку выдает, MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: "Unknown column 'TABLE_SHEMA' in 'where clause'".  тоесть не находит. помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Comment: А вот теперь самое время приглядеться к опечаткам в именах полей.

Comment: у меня есть несколько баз данных , я хочу использовать конкретно базу данных под именем 'dslam'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

исправил, ошибка в синтактиксе запросах

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'dslam
```

где dslam имя базы данных